# How send tmux prefixer to remote server using iterm2

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, tmux, iterm2

This is my first time using tmux and I have a problem.

I have a remote server that I am connecting to it using ssh(using iterm2). Since opened, when I try to send commands like ctrl+b+c command+b+c to create new window it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl+b or Command+b called Prefix  , in order to create new window which is done using (Prefix c) which exactly mean

```
Press Ctrl+b or Command+b
remove your fingers from keyboard
Press c alone
```